# Re-download my app from google play dashboard

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I uploaded my android app to the google play store and literally 10 mins. later my computer crashes whipping out all of my files/folders/pics (including my app files)...

Here's my question. Can I somehow download my app from the google play dashboard and import my app into my eclipse software I used to build my app?

Comment: Restore your data from repository or backup.

Comment: +Marcin I didn't make a backup

Comment: So now you see why you should start.

Comment: No. Maybe check out SpinRite to recover your files?

Comment: +Marcin I've started my computer in safe mode. Saved all of the files to two removable hard discs, then uploaded those same files my microsoft onedrive account. I now have everything safely back. I'm now in the process of importing my project

Comment: Good you recovered. Hope you learned the lesson though, as next time you might be less lucky :) Remote repo (github or bitbucket) is next step to consider

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] The short answer is no. As a possible next-best thing, see below:

As mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en), what is uploaded to the store is the .apk file - a packaged version of your project rather than the project files. It is apparently possible to derive the source from the apk, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file).

Comment: No, reverse engeneering is not "restoring project files"

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Agreed, but it's a step in the right direction - apologies for the sloppy language.